# jQueryMobile & timers - stop previous timer on ajax page load, variable scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, timer, countdown

I have run into a snafoo using jQuery Mobile, backbone, and regular ole javascript timers.  The web app has an idle timer that on runs on two sequential pages.  The problem is that the way I am currently handling events (wrapping everything in pageshow), my tests reveal that the timer from the first page continues to run in addition to the second timer instantiated on the subsequent pageshow event - resulting in a flicker of the session countdown (two instances of the countdown variable being displayed simultaneously).

I tried checking to see if the `idleInterval` already existed to no avail (result was always that it didn't exist).

I imagine I could listen for one of the other 'pagechange' events - like one that is triggered at the very start and stop the previous timer - however then I would have to wrap different parts of code inside different 'pagechange' events and thus have scope issues (need to refer to same backbone models in either case).  What a mess...

```
$(document).on('pageinit pageshow', 'div:jqmData(role="page"), div:jqmData(role="dialog")', function (event) {
    if($(this).attr("id")!="KioskDefaultLogin" && $(this).hasClass('kiosk-mode') && event.type=='pageshow') {

       ...backbone js code...

       function sessionTimeout() {

        var inactivetime = 0;
        console.log('TIMER EXISTS?=>'+window.hasOwnProperty('idleInterval'));

        if( qnumerItem.get("state") != "login") {

            var idleInterval = setInterval(function(){

                if(qnumerItem.get("state") != "timeout") {

                    inactivetime ++;
                    console.log('TIMER -----'+inactivetime+'------');
                }

                ////console.log("timer 1: "+inactivetime);
                /*Edit the inactivetime value here to change the idle session timer*/
                if (inactivetime == 15 && qnumerItem.get("state") != "timeout") {

                    qnumerItem.changeState("timeout");
                    inactivetime=0;

                    /*End Session Due to Inactivity Countdown*/
                    $(function(){
                        var count=30;
                        console.log("I STARTED");
                        var countdown = setInterval(function(){

                            //$(".ui-page-active .session-countdown").html(count);
                            //$(".ui-page-active .to-phrase").show();
                            if (count == 0) {
                                clearInterval(countdown);
                                qnumerItem.changeState("kill");
                            }
                            count--;
                            console.log("timer 1: "+inactivetime);
                            console.log("timer 2: "+count);
                        }, 1000);

                        $(this).on( 'click', '.to-continue', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            clearInterval(countdown);
                            $("#session-countdown").html(60);
                        });
                        $(this).on( 'click', '.to-end', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            clearInterval(countdown);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }, 1000); // 1 second
        }

        //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            inactivetime = 0;
        }, false);

        document.addEventListener('touchmove',
            function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);

        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            inactivetime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            inactivetime = 0;
        });
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            inactivetime = 0;
        });

    }

        sessionTimeout();

...more code....
```